# Entity Framework Association with Filter

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following model in my model:

```
Patient

Vendor

Organization
```

each of these entities needs Addresses.

The Address basically looks like the following

```
Address
  AddressTypeId // with Navigation Property/Association to AddressType
  EntityKey // indicates the PK Id of the entity this address is for

AddressType
  EntityId // indicates the entity type this address type corresponds to (Patient or Vendor)
  // This should be on the AddressType, not the Address, since we need a way of knowing what kind of AddressTypes are available to create for new addresses for Patients, Vendors, and Organizations
  //...that is Patients support AddressType X, Vendors support AddressType Y, etc.
```

I want to create an association for Patient, Vendor, and Organization on the EntityKey property on Address - each with a filter constraint that the Address's AddressType.EntityId is the matching EntityId for that entity (1 for Patient, 2 for Vendor, 3 for Address).

What is the best way of doing this? Most ORM's on the market support this kind of scenario....and it's certainly a very common one.

NOTE: I don't want to create PatientAddress/PatientAddressType, VendorAddress/VendorAddressType, and OrganizationAddress/OrganizationAddress type derived entities. It severely clutters the model and makes it basically incomprehensible.

Right now I'm solving this by doing explicit joins in my LINQ queries:

```
const int patientTypeEntityId = 1;
var query = from p in repository.Patients
              let addresses = repository.Addresses.Where(a => 
                  a.EntityKey == p.Id & a.AddressType.EntityId == patientTypeEntityId)
              select new { Patient = p, Addresses = a }
```

but I don't want to continue having to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have an address collection in your `Patient`, `Vendor`, etc...

```
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int EntityKey { get; set; }
    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
}
```

... and somehow tell EF that `Patient.Addresses` only gets populated with addresses of address type "Patient".

I think that is not possible for several reasons:

- If you don't expose the foreign key in `Address` (no `EntityKey` property there) you have to tell EF the key in the mapping (otherwise it would create/assume two different FK columns):

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
      .HasMany(p => p.PVAddresses)
      .WithRequired()
      .Map(a => a.MapKey("EntityKey"));

  modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
      .HasMany(p => p.PVAddresses)
      .WithRequired()
      .Map(a => a.MapKey("EntityKey"));
  ```

This throws an exception due to the duplicate "EntityKey" column for two different relationships.

- Next thing we could try is to expose the foreign key as property in `Address` (`EntityKey` property is there) and then use this mapping:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
      .HasMany(p => p.PVAddresses)
      .WithRequired()
      .HasForeignKey(a => a.EntityKey);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Vendor>()
      .HasMany(p => p.PVAddresses)
      .WithRequired()
      .HasForeignKey(a => a.EntityKey);
  ```

This (surprisingly) doesn't throw an exception but creates two FK constraints in the database between `Patient`-`Address` and `Vendor`-`Address` with the same FK column `EntityKey`. For your model, I think, this doesn't make sense because it would require that always a `Patient` *and* a `Vendor` with the same PK exists if you have an address with some `EntityKey`. So, you would have to remove these FK constraints in the DB manually (which feels very hacky to me).

- And the last thing is that you cannot specify a filter for lazy and eager loading of navigation properties. The `Addresses` collection would always get populated with the addresses which have the same `EntityKey` as the PK of `Patient` or `Vendor` respectively. You can apply a filter though with explicite loading:

  ```
  var patient = context.Patients.Single(p => p.Id == 1);
  context.Entry(patient).Collection(p => p.Addresses).Query()
      .Where(a => a.Addresstype.EntityId == patientTypeEntityId)
      .Load();
  ```

But you would have to ensure that you never use lazy or eager loading for the `Addresses` collection. So, this is not really a solution and we should forget it immediately.

The ugliest point for me is that you cannot have FK constraints on the `EntityKey`. In other words: The DB allows to have an EntityKey = 1 with no referenced `Patient` or `Vendor` with that PK (because somehow the patient 1 and vendor 1 have been deleted, for example).

For this reason alone I would prefer the solution shown by @Akash - aside from the fact that it is probably the only working and clean solution with EF at all.

Comment: You mean having one nullable FK column per related entity type? And how would I enforce the constraint that an Address for a Patient doesn't have an AddressType for an Organization? With business logic alone? It seems like I'd be violating DRY.

Comment: @JeffN825: Yes, with business logic alone. Basically I meant that using three nullable FK columns is the only way which would make things easy *from EF viewpoint* because it's the only way you could define navigation collections from `Patient`, `Vendor`, etc. to the addresses which EF would automatically handle as you want it. Three nullable FKs also have drawbacks, like: how to ensure that always only one is not null? But how would you enforce the constraint in the DB? Your `EntityKey` is just a column, not an FK. Your model consistency requires business logic, DB can't help and EF neither.

Comment: DB is fairly easy - that can be done with triggers. It's unfortunately that EF can't support this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So your advice would be to have all those (in reality 15) nullable FK columns? Or to keep doing things the way I am? Thanks.

Comment: @JeffN825: Oh, 15 is a lot. I can't tell what to do. It depends too much on your whole application and what you have to change/test/redesign when you introduce the navigation collections and the FKs. If I would start a project I would probably use the 15 FK columns, yes. But I'm talking from theory, not experience with such a model. Perhaps ask an additional question (under SQLServer/EF) tag if 15 FKs could be a problem (performance? the constraint that only one must be non-null? ...) or if other people see alternatives. This decision seems to be important enough to ask more than one question.